# Given that $X(\omega)$ is an integrable random variable, when is $g(X(\omega))$ integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Dear StackExchange community

It is well-known that if $X(\omega)$ is a (real-valued) random variable, then $g(X(\omega))$ is $σ(X)$-measurable if $g$ is a Borel-measurable function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The converse is also true: any $σ(X)$-measurable random variable can be expressed as $g(X(\omega))$, where $g$ is some Borel-measurable function.

I wonder if there is a similar neat way to characterize the class of functions $g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for any **integrable** random variable $X$, $g(X)$ produce **integrable $σ(X)$-measurable** random variables and only them? (Of course, integrability in this context is just the existence of a finite expected value)

- This class is smaller than the class of Borel-measurable functions,
  because Borel-measurable functions produce all $σ(X)$-measurable
  random variables, not only integrable
- This class is larger than the class of bounded Borel-measurable
  functions, because bounded Borel-measurable functions produce some
  but not all integrable $σ(X)$-measurable random variables (i.e.
  boundedness guarantees integrability but there are integrable random
  variables that are unbounded).